# Adding Grails command to Maven phases -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, grails, maven, build

I need to build my Grails project with Maven, and it is necessary to add an additional grails command. I'm using the grails-maven-plugin to create the pom file, and I can build the war file with `$ mvn package`

While building this application, I will need to execute another grails command, one the does not correspond directly to any of the maven build phases. Referring to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.5%20Ant%20and%20Maven), I'm adding a second execution element to the grails-maven plugin, as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>init</goal>
          <goal>maven-clean</goal>
          <goal>validate</goal>
          <goal>config-directories</goal>
          <goal>maven-compile</goal>
          <goal>maven-test</goal>
          <goal>maven-war</goal>
          <goal>maven-functional-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stats</id>
        <phase>init</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <command>stats</command>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

For this example I'm trying to execute `grails stats` in the maven init phase. (Eventually, stats will be replaced by something more useful.) when I run:

```
$ mvn package
```

the ouput includes:

```
[INFO] [grails:validate {execution: default}]
[INFO] [grails:init {execution: default}]
[INFO] [grails:config-directories {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
```

which evidently doesn't contain the execution of `grails stats`. I am able to execute the stats command through Maven directly, in the following way:

```
$ mvn grails:exec -Dcommand=stats
```

it only fails to execute when added as a goal in the pom.

I'm using Java 1.5.0_22, Grails 1.3.7, and Maven 2.2.1.

Comment: At this point I'd be willing to award the bounty to someone that can point me to a forum, email list, or person that can answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my problem was confusing goals and Maven phases. Notice I was trying

```
<phase>init</phase>
```

and I had tried other items from the list of goals, but these are not Maven phases.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information I could find about this plugin, you should add the `grails:` prefix to your goals.

I have no experience with this plugin, so I could be wrong =)

References:

- http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-maven-plugin-version-td2284532.html
- http://www.grails.org/Maven+Integration

so for example: `<goal>grails:init</goal>`

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite helpful. That only works for those grails commands which have been wrapped as maven commands.